# login page via popu-up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an example login page via a pop-up window?
Also, if the user performs some operation on the site that requires authentication, then show the login screen (if user not authorized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just create you Login view, as you would implement it usually. And then apply fancybox (http://fancybox.net/) or bootstrap-modal(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) to make it work as modal.

Regarding re-direction: as soon as you use [Authorize] attribute as controller attribute and not-authorized user tries to hit its action, he will be redirected automatically;

Answer (score 0):

you may use modal box plugins for jquery to create pop-up and place your log-in form in the pop-up.

Check out this modal window plugin which support html markup in the popup.
http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin